# Telerik Reports, spanning data across columns in a grid

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a telerik report (using Telerik.Reporting plugin Q1 2013 SP1)  based on the following sql

```
       select productId from products
```

I have the following design

[image]

The output is

[image]

How would I get the system to populate all of the columns with ProductIds, so each column is a ProductId, so we have 3 products on one line. It  seems simple yet im struggling to see a simple solution

Here it is in simple tabular form, this is how I want the report to look:-

[image]

Comment: Would you please show us some more code. Where do you define your report? 
And if you want to populate the other columns, why don't you select more columns in your sql statement?
Plus: What platform are we talking about? Is this Telerik Reports, Kendo UI? WebForms, WPF or just plain html?

Comment: As Marco said : **"why don't you select more columns in your sql statement?"** This is the real question. As Telerik report is mainly gui and design I can be hard to show code. And platform could be irrevelant in this simple case as Telerik report could be kind of stand alone.

Comment: @WelshKing 3 product per row is that a nested table ?

Comment: @PierreLebon, that sounds more like a simple listview than a grid layout to me. (Sorry I can only talk in Kendo UI terms; no experience with reporting)

Comment: Can you edit your question with a simple excel showing the input and expected result. I just don't get it.

Comment: @WelshKing, Ok now I get it. The only way I see is to use 3 Table one per column and using a modulo % on the DataIndex. But a little voice is crying inside. For every data component of the report 1 row = 1 row of data. SQL Split it in 3 or you do it in 3 table and filter on index%. And then modulo 1 will be fun to configure.

Comment: @WelshKing ask it on Telerik forum too! Because the documentation on reporting is really poor. We need expert.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-reports-spanning-data-across-columns-in-a-grid